# Maximum of $(c^Tx)^2/c^TAc$ with some conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^k$, and $A$ be a $k\times k$ positive definite matrix. Suppose that $y^TA^{-1}x=0$. Show that
$$
x^T A^{-1}x=\max_{c\in\mathbb{R}^k,c\neq 0, c^Ty=0} \frac{(c^Tx)^2}{c^TAc}.
$$

---

**My solution:**

We can decompose as  $A=Q^T\Lambda Q$, where $Q$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Substituting $z=\Lambda^{1/2}Q^Tc$,
we have $c=Q\Lambda^{-1/2}z$ and:
$$
\frac{(c^Tx)^2}{c^TAc} = \frac{(x^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}z)^2}{z^Tz}
= \frac{z^T\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Txx^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}z}{z^Tz}.
$$
So the maximization problem turns into:
$$
\max_{z\in\mathbb{R}^k,z\neq 0, z^T\Lambda^{1/2}Q^Ty=0} \frac{z^T\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Txx^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}z}{z^Tz}.
$$
The objective is standard Rayleigh quitient. Let's try to consider the problem ignoring constraints first. Since
$$
\mathrm{rank}\left(\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Txx^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}\right) \leq \mathrm{rank}\left(xx^T\right) =1,
$$
$\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Txx^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}$ can have at most one non-zero eigenvalue. Letting $z=\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Tx$, we can verify $z$ is an eigenvecor of $\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Txx^TQ\Lambda^{-1/2}$ with eigenvalue $x^TQ\Lambda^{-1} Q^Tx=x^TA^{-1}x>0$. It means $x^T A^{-1}x$ is the maximum value of the Rayleigh quotient. Happily, $z=\Lambda^{-1/2}Q^Tx$ satisfies all the conditions for the maximization problem.

---

**My question:**

I'm not convinced because I didn't use the conditions ${c\in\mathbb{R}^k,c\neq 0, c^Ty=0}$.  It seems to have worked out luckily. Can I ask correctness of my solution or any other approaches?